# Receiving Notifications/Indications on Ionic 2 Framework (BLE-Plugin)

Tags: android, notifications, ionic2, bluetooth-lowenergy, cordova-plugins

I't trying to received notifications/indications from a connected BLE-Device from Ionic-Application (on Android).
Reading and writing of Characteristics is working, if I activate notifications they are set on the BLE-Device. It will send data to my application, but I get no data.

If the page is loaded, I check the connection state. If the application is connected, I start notification and write data to the device.

Here is how I activate the notifications.

```
BLE.startNotification("MAC-Address", "service-UUID", "characteristic-UUID").subscribe(buffer => {
    this.notificationReceived(buffer);
});
BLE.write("MAC-Address", "service-UUID", "characteristic-UUID", start.buffer)
  .then(data => {
      console.log('prepared for download, wait for response');
  }, error => {
    console.error('Failed to initialize Data transfer ' + error);
  });
```

The notificationReceived is called once, just before BLE.write. The notifications are enabled on the BLE-Device (I have added some debug-outputs on it). In the debug-outputs of the BLE-Device I can see it will send a notification, but in the Ionic-App I receive nothing.

Anybody a hint for me what I could check? I'm new to TypeScript, so this could be anything, I have no Ideas what I could check next.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was:
There was no Problem.

The Notification was received, just before the output of the write response.